# Nexus 5 touch response is slow while charging

Tags: usb, charging, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

My problem is simple. Touch response of my Nexus 5 is very slow while charging. I can't even unlock the pattern while charging. I need to draw it very slowly. My OS is Android 4.4.2.

I have been charging from Laptop USB port. **I am seeing this issue for the first time on my mobile. I have used it while charging before.**

I am charging with **original USB cable** that comes with phone. I also tried USB cable of my old nokia C5. Both responds similarly. (Earlier both worked fine).

**I checked it in safe mode and problem still exists.**

**UPDATE 12-Feb-2014:**

1. The above-mentioned problem occured when I connected my phone to laptop USB via stock USB cable in my **college lab**. After reaching home, the phone works fine, both in USB charging and AC charging.
2. I tried charging with both USB and AC power in my lab. And the problem exists. I even tried them with Debugging mode turned off and problem is still there.

*So I strongly suspect some problem with AC power supply in my lab. Anyway to check it?*

Does anyone face this issue? Any fixes?

Comment: Can you switch on "Show touch points" in Developer Options ? Check if there are any phantom touches when the charger is fixed, it could explain your touch being lost

Comment: @AadiDroid : I did as you said and I couldn't find any phantom touches.

Comment: Please try on AC Power, this is a known issue with quite a few phones! In fact I had this issue with my N7000 running CM10, the phone is just lying around now.

Just to be sure, is USB debugging off ?

Comment: phone damaged? USB debugging is on. I will check on AC and comment later.

Comment: switch off debugging and try !

Comment: I updated my question. Regarding debugging, i will try it from my lab.

Comment: problem exists in my lab power supply with debugging off. So I think some problem with lab power supply.

Comment: Just to see if that is the issue for me, I tried different sockets at home with my old phone! It varies based on the power supply :) All I can say is stop charging through these faulty places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Moving from comments to answer]

This could be an issue with either debugging mode switched on or the power source itself!

Please try on AC Power, this is a known issue with quite a few phones! In fact I had this issue with my N7000 running CM10, the phone is just lying around now. Just to be sure, is USB debugging off ? Just to see if that is the issue for me, I tried different sockets at home with my old phone! It varies based on the power supply. All I can say is stop charging through these faulty places